# Can we store NSURLRequest directly into Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am developing iPad Application in which i need to create Multiple NSURLRequest.
When is it fails I need to fire that URL request again.

I have three type (Create School, Create Floor and Create Rooms) of request which contain multiple parameters different create Request.

There is retrial method which can fire when there is internet available with same object which was created on first request.

So I was trying to create  three Tables and I was trying to store all parameter with their status.

Is it possible to create Single Table with NSURLRequest irrespective of CREATE REQUEST?

Comment: You can't store an `NSURLRequest` directly in Core Data. You can only store `NSManagedObject` instances. You can create an entity that allows you to store the information you need to recreate the request.

Comment: `NSURLRequest` is `NS(Secure)Coding` Compliant, so it should be translated into `NSData`. That's a possibility.

Comment: @Larme You are saying we need to convert NSURL request into NSData type. correct? If it saved in DB as NSData than how do we know which request is send to server. Do we need to decode NSData and than send to server?

Comment: You would save it as a property of a managed object. That object would probably identify itself in some way so that you could make sense of its properties. You might want to review Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data entities correspond to instances of `NSManagedObject` or a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, so you can't just save URL requests directly. What you could do is create an entity called something like `SavedRequest` that has a property representing the URL request-- and maybe some other details about the request (whatever other info you might need-- date, maybe?).

Since `NSURLRequest` conforms to `NSCoding`, you would create this property using the Core Data "transformable" type. Core Data would use `NSCoding` to automatically convert to/from `NSData` as needed. You would assign an `NSURLRequest` to the property and read them back, and Core Data would save them as `NSData`.

Given your description though, Core Data might not make sense. It sounds like you just want to save a list of URL requests and later read it back, and don't need the extra features Core Data would provide. It would be simpler to put your `NSURLRequest` objects in an array and then save that array to a file or to user defaults. You would convert to/from `NSData` yourself, but since you can use `NSCoding` that's easy.

To save the array you'd do something like this, assuming an array called `myArray` containing URL requests and a path in `filePath`:

```
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myArray toFile:filePath];
```

You'd get the array back using

```
NSArray *savedRequests = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 2):

So I came up with my own idea I am sharing with all.

As per I read and googling , I can not store NSURLRequest into core data. because I don't know type of object.

I will create core data table with column PARAMS, METHODS, URL

So can I create Table which will contain column of PARAMS (Dict), Methods (PUT, GET etc), URL.

What I will do that I can convert DICT params into NSKeyedArchiver and save it into PARAM column. URL and METHODS in separate column.

When ever I need save request, I can grab it from table and send to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just save the `absoluteString` of the NSURLRequest’s `URL` property. Or do they each have distinct timeouts or cache policies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible, at least with Swift. With Swift you can access  the Transformable property in CoreData. Using this property it is possible to put any kind of data in Core Data. That even without extra overhead.

See the excellent tutorial http://geekyviney.blogspot.nl/2015/02/transformable-binary-data-properties-in.html

Comment: Swift has no concept of a "transformable" property. Core Data has one.